# Подключение dll библиотек к jar

Tags: java, dll, jar

При подключении dll библиотек к проекту в NetBeans с помощью параметра -Djava.library.path все работает нормально, однако после компиляции и запуска jar файла, выдается ошибка, связанная с отсутствием данных dll файлов. Можно ли как-то загрузить эти dll в jar файл или прописать путь к ним?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте положить эти библиотеки в той же директории, где лежит сам "jar", например в папку ".lib\*.dll".
При запуске ""jar`a добавить параметр:

> java -Djava.library.path=.\lib\ -jar *.jar

поправил

Comment: К сожалению, это ни к чему не привело. Ошибка как была, так и осталась.

Comment: Проблема решилась методом проб и ошибок. Оказывается надо было данный параметр писать перед -jar *.jar.

Comment: отлично(-_-) да это я что-то перепутал обычно такие параметры всегда вначале идут